# Lifetime in Hours of Electronic Tubes Random Variable Question

Tags: statistics

I was working through this question and I'm not sure where to proceed from here or even if my answer is correct.

Question is:

The lifetime in hours of electronic tubes is a random variable having a probability density function given by:

f(x) = a^2 * (xe^(-ax)), x >= 0

Compute the expected lifetime of such a tube.

I integrated the function over 0 to infinity and got:

a^2 * ( -x^2 e^(-ax) ) /a

+

2( -xe^(-ax))

+

-(e^-ax)

from 0 to infinity. I'm need sure if my result is correct and, if it is, where to go from here since infinity is a value to be plugged in and a is a variable(?) that I'm treating as a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected life time is:
$$
E(X)=\int_{x=0}^{\infty}xf(x)\;dx=\int_{x=0}^{\infty}x^2a^2e^{-ax}\;dx
$$
Now the integral $\int x^2a^2e^{-ax}\;dx$ is obviously a quadratic polynomial in $x$ times $e^{-ax}$ plus a constant of integration. Taking such a candidate for the integral differentiating it and equating the coefficients of corresponding terms gives:
$$
\int x^2a^2e^{-ax}\;dx=-\left[ax^2+2x+\frac{2}{a}\right]e^{-ax}+C
$$
Hence:
$$
E(X)=\int_{x=0}^{\infty}x^2a^2e^{-ax}\;dx=\frac{2}{a}
$$
(What you need to know here is that $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^ue^{-x}=0$ for all $u\in \mathbb{R}$)